# Can we create a separate DOM instance inside of a web component without using iframes?

Tags: javascript, html

I created an Angular component for demonstrating responsive designs which you can view a simple demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdlkej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).  Inside this component I use an `<iframe>` to show the responsiveness because it creates its own separate DOM instance from the rest of the application so if we apply a width of `30vw` to the element inside of the `<iframe>` it will respond to the size of the `<iframe>` rather than the user's screen.

One drawback to this component is Firefox doesn't allow us to programmatically embed components directly into the iframe while Chrome and Edge allow it.  So in order for it to work in Firefox I have to create a page for each component I want to demonstrate and pass in the URL.  While this works perfectly fine it has to load the entire app in order to navigate to that page which means if I have 10 demonstrations on one page the user's device will be loading the website 10 additional times which even with lazy loading is a lot more resources than it needs to take.

I watched a video earlier about web components and saw how they were working with the `shadowDOM` and had to take similar measures to pass data and styling into the web component which got me wondering if I can just create web component that does the same thing.

I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Optiq/pen/VwVRYJV) to see if it had its' own DOM instance and as is it doesn't.  I tried looking further into this but so far haven't found anything about it.  Also I noticed that for some reason the `resize: both` property isn't working in this demo which I don't understand so if someone can figure out why that's happening that would be appreciated as well.  But all in all I figured if it is indeed possible to do this it would be a lot easier to work with than an iframe and using the `broadcastChannel` api to pass data back and forth.  Is this possible?

Comment: Chrome and Edge are basically the same, they both use chromium under the hood. Safari/webkit is the third Browser you might want to also support.

Comment: `srcdoc` is supported by firefox, maybe you could use it instead and work with html?

Comment: @SimonLaux ok I experimented with that idea and I can't find a way to get it to work.  When I pass the component into the `srcdoc` property I just see `[object object]` in the iframe.  I've also used `AngularElements` to create web components but I can't figure out how to pass the .js file into the iframe to register it.

Comment: When you have a dynamic server then you could serve custom html files in your component. maybe you can also fake some files via a service worker. Other than that if you set the right sandbox and CSP properties on the iframe and load an iframe.html from the same origin (host and port) then you can access the window element of the iframe via js code and use document.create element to create script tags and inject everything. `srcdoc` is only for html as string.

Comment: can you show me an example of this?